# is there a way to trigger a scan with a running robocopy

Tags: robocopy

When robocopy is in memory resident/timed mode i want to trigger a scan/update programmatically from another process.

Is there a way such as raising an event or sending a message to the robocopy process to interrupt the wait period and do an immediate scan?

Comment: It may be easier to terminate the process, and restarting it to do the scan/update.

Comment: Thats a good idea Strom I will pursue it